# are there debugging options for ld

Tags: debugging, gcc, assembly, gdb, ld

I have written an assembly program that, for testing purposes, just exits. The code is as follows:

```
section .text
  _global start
_start:
  mov    eax, 1
  mov    ebx, 0
  int    0x80
```

The program is obviously in 32-bit; however, I am using 1 64-bit processor and operating system, so I compiled it (using nasm) and linked it as follows:

```
nasm -f elf exit.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -s -o exit exit.o
```

debugging the program with gdb, I can't list the code since there are no debugging symbols.

```
(gdb) list
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

In using gcc, you can use the options -ggdb to load the symbols while compiling a c file. but since I don't how to use gcc to compile 32-bit assembly for 64-bit machines (I have searched this but can't find a solution,) I am forced to use ld. can I load the debugging symbols using ld? sorry for the long question and the excess information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to assemble with `nasm -g -F dwarf -f elf exit.asm`. The linker does not create debugging symbols, you have to tell the linker to generate them. If debugging information is present the linker will automatically link it in.

Comment: Unless this doesn't work in for 32 bit code for some reason, you can force nasm to export debugging symbols by using `nasm -felf -g -l exit.lst exit.asm`

Comment: @fuz `nasm -g -F dwarf -f elf exit.asm` didn't work

Comment: @DarkEagle “didn't work” is not an error description. What happens exactly? Where is the error?

Comment: @jefferson using `nasm -felf -g -l exit.lst exit.asm` didn't work too

Comment: @fuzz there are still no debugging symbols. gdb can't load them

Comment: @DarkEagle Perhaps that's because you also pass `-s` to ld which removes all symbols (including debugging symbols!). You might want to get rid of that.

Comment: @fuzz sorry fuzz, that worked. using `nasm -g -F dwarf -f elf exit.asm` and then removing the -s parameter worked. Thanks a lot fuzz!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debugging information is generated by `nasm` when you pass `-g`. Additionally, you also need to specify what type of debugging information you want (typically dwarf), which is done with the `-F` switch. So to assemble your file, write

```
nasm -f elf -F dwarf -g file.asm
```

then link without `-s` to preserve the symbol table and debugging information:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -o file file.o
```

Comment: For short, you can run `nasm -felf -gdwarf -o file.o file.asm` since `-gformat` is equivalent to `-g -F format`, source `man nasm`.

Answer (score 4):

The `-s` switch tells ld to "strip" the debugging info. Lose that!

Comment: Wait, using the `nasm -g -F dwarf -f elf exit.asm` then removing the -s parameter worked. Thanks a lot!